# Windows DLL injection with Go

Tags: windows, go, x86-64, dll-injection

I'm working on a task which needs to inject a DLL to a process to check if a vulnerability on a system exists. The program runs but doesn't take any effect; the dll file cannot be loaded to the process (in this case, `Notepad`). Is there something wrong with this piece of code? Moreover, this can run properly only when compiled with `GOARCH=386`. How can I compile and run this with normal mode `GOARCH=amd64`?

This is my work so far:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main(){
    dllPath, _ := syscall.FullPath(os.Args[1])
    var token windows.Token
    var tp windows.Tokenprivileges
    var privName string = "SeDebugPrivilege"
    privStr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(privName)
    hCurrentProc, _ := windows.GetCurrentProcess()
    windows.OpenProcessToken(hCurrentProc, syscall.TOKEN_QUERY|syscall.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token)
    windows.LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, privStr, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid)
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = windows.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED
    err = windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, false, &tp, 0, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("notepad.exe")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}

    cmd.Start()

    cmdPid := cmd.Process.Pid
    fmt.Println(cmdPid)

    hProc, err := w32.OpenProcess(w32.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(cmdPid))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    dwMemSize := len(dllPath) + 1
    lpRemoteMem, err := w32.VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, dwMemSize, w32.MEM_RESERVE|w32.MEM_COMMIT, w32.PAGE_READWRITE)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = w32.WriteProcessMemory(hProc, uint32(lpRemoteMem), []byte(dllPath), uint(dwMemSize))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    moduleKernel, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    lpLoadLibrary, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(moduleKernel, "LoadLibraryW")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    hThread, _, err := w32.CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, uint32(lpLoadLibrary), lpRemoteMem, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    w32.ResumeThread(hThread)
    w32.WaitForSingleObject(hThread, syscall.INFINITE)
    exitCode, err := w32.GetExitCodeProcess(hProc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    } else {
        log.Println(exitCode)
    }
    w32.CloseHandle(hThread)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your system probably has two copies of notepad, `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe` and `C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\notepad.exe`.   Which one are you testing with?

Comment: These bits of code assuredly will not work correctly with any 64-bit architecture: `uint32(lpRemoteMem)`, `uint32(lpLoadLibrary)`  Instead you must use `uintptr`

Comment: "this can run properly only when compiled with GOARCH=386" what problem specifically do you have compiling with amd64?

Comment: @Ben Voigt I'm currently testing with the 1st one, since the default process called by `exec.Command` will be it

Comment: @Adrian when compiled with `GOARCH=amd64`, `WriteProcessMemory` panics since the address is not properly converted. I guess it's the conflict from `uint32`

Comment: «since the address is not properly converted. I guess it's the conflict from `uint32`»: not conflict: on amd64 type-converting an address to `uint32` essentially truncates it (zeroes the upper part of the address out), so I'm sure @BenVoigt's comment is spot-on.

Comment: @MargaretNguyen: When you do `GetProcAddress` inside your 32-bit Go code, you're getting the address of `LoadLibrary` from inside C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\kernel32.dll.  That address means nothing to a running instance of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\notepad.exe, which is using the 64-bit kernel32.dll

Comment: @Adrian I'm not sure about this but it raises an exception of "writing to invalid memory" when I compiled the program with `amd64`, therefore I must turn it into `386` in order for the program to not crash

Comment: @BenVoigt I've tested again with the `SYSWOW64` version but still meet this problem. Beside, the library does not let me to use `uintptr` instead of `uint32`

Comment: You cannot write to memory in a 64-bit process using 32-bit addresses. Unless the library provides a 64-bit capable version of `WriteProcessMemory` you cannot use it. Also consider the repercussions of using a non-systems programming language to do systems programming.

Comment: Crossposted over there [on `r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/m379id/dll_injection_with_golang/).

Comment: @IInspectable, Go is actually fine for this sort of thing (if used correctly). Still, I admit "bare" knowledge of Go is insufficient to properly do Win32 API in it.

Comment: @kos This is clearly the build up to injecting actual code into a target process. By that time you will likely want to write the payload to inject using the same programming language as your injector. That's when Go stops being able to deliver.

Comment: @IInspectable: It's not transferring shellcode, it's remotely loading a DLL.  It's already a complete example for doing so (loading the DLL identified by `dllpath`), not a buildup.  And why wouldn't Go be able to build a DLL (Honest question I don't use Go myself)?

Comment: @ben Go requires a runtime. Go requires a garbage collector. Go requires you to use its own allocator. Go forces you to use green threading. You *might* be able to compile Go code into a DLL, but that DLL is virtually useless outside a Go application. Contrast that with C or Rust.

Comment: @IInspectable, what you have written appears to be a straw-man attack ;-) The OP is merely trying to inject a DLL into a running process—that basically amounts to making a couple Win32 API calls. GC, own allocator and alleged forced using of green threading have no bearing on the task at hand, so… what is your point, exactly? I could probably do the same in Python or Ruby as they both have means to do FFI and, by extension, call into Win32 API. I mean, buildup, ROP, shellcode and all this stuff is definitely more 1337 but it's outside the scope of the original problem ;-)

Comment: @kos I was commenting on *"the repercussions of using a non-systems programming language to do systems programming"*. In case of the question, as asked, writing shell code isn't immediately required. Though any serious attack **will** require that sort of code. And it is at that point where Go can no longer deliver. Call it off as a *"straw-man attack"* all day long.